# Using PVCS (Serena) Source Control for Visual Studio web development

Tags: asp.net, visual-sourcesafe

Has anyone had any experuience using web-based PVCS (Serena) source control app for Visual Studio ASP.NET web development in a multi-developer environment?

Due to the lack of integration with VS, I fear that we will have chaos with files not being checked into the repository because, I believe, VSS or TFS normally handles adding files to the repositiory, many of which that aren't directly edited by the developer.

What are your experiences with this source control application? Any recommended best practices? using open source is not an issue in this Orwellian environment.

Comment: PVCS seems to be a Lotus Notes of VCSes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having used PVCS for a large scale project I would suggest avoiding it completely. The product is slow, real slow, and not does not support atomic checkins.

Their branching model worked well 20 years ago but falls short of today's reality. Labels galore.

If youhave a lot of files be prepared to wait. We have over 10K files in out enterprise application. A checkout alone would be a 20 minute affair.

Best practices? Don't use it. If you must then get Beyond Compare! The diff included with PVCS is useless.

Open Source? **Subversion** is a massive improvement over **PVCS** or go with a distributed solution (Git, Mercurial, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Serena Dimension is integrated with Visual Studio. There is a plugin to install. It works very well. Better than Tortoise for SVN i.e.